# I have DataFrame's columns and data in list i want to put the relevant data to relevant column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

suppose you have given list of all item you can have and separately you have list of data and whose shape of list is not fixed it may contain any number of item  you wished to create a dataframe from it and you have to put it on write column
for example

```
columns = ['shirt','shoe','tie','hat']
data = [['hat','tie'],
        ['shoe', 'tie', 'shirt'],
        ['tie', 'shirt',]]
# and from this I wants to create a dummy variable like this 
  shirt  shoe  tie  hat
0   0     0     1    1
1   1     1     1    0
2   1     0     1    0
```

Comment: Do you need count values or indicators? It means if changed `['hat','tie']` to `['hat','tie', 'hat']` in first row for `hat` is `1` for indicator or `2` for count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want indicator columns filled by `0` and `1` only use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if want change ordering of columns by list and if possible some value not exist add only `0` column:

```
columns = ['shirt','shoe','tie','hat']
data = [['hat','tie'],
        ['shoe', 'tie', 'shirt'],
        ['tie', 'shirt',]]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data),columns=mlb.classes_)
        .reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df)
   shirt  shoe  tie  hat
0      0     0    1    1
1      1     1    1    0
2      1     0    1    0
```

Or [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.Series(data).str.join('|').str.get_dummies().reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   shirt  shoe  tie  hat
0      0     0    1    1
1      1     1    1    0
2      1     0    1    0
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-cf20df1c4afd> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
      2 mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
----> 3 df = (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data),columns =mlb.classes_).reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0))

NameError: name 'columns' is not defined

Comment: @DarkstarDream - It is from your solution `columns = ['shirt','shoe','tie','hat']`

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `collections.Counter`.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter
columns = ['shirt','shoe','tie','hat']
data = [['hat','tie'],
        ['shoe', 'tie', 'shirt'],
        ['tie', 'shirt']]

data = map(Counter, data)
#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   shirt  shoe  tie  hat
0      0     0    1    1
1      1     1    1    0
2      1     0    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting data to a dataframe:

```
data = [['hat','tie'],
        ['shoe', 'tie', 'shirt'],
        ['tie', 'shirt',]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

     0       1      2
0   hat     tie     None
1   shoe    tie     shirt
2   tie    shirt    None
```

Them use:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).groupby(level=0).agg('sum')

   hat  shirt   shoe    tie
0   1   0       0       1
1   0   1       1       1
2   0   1       0       1
```

Explanation:

df.stack() returns a MultiIndex Series:

```
0  0      hat
   1      tie
1  0     shoe
   1      tie
   2    shirt
2  0      tie
   1    shirt
dtype: object
```

If we get the dummy values of this series we get:

```
       hat  shirt    shoe   tie
0   0   1   0           0       0
    1   0   0           0       1
1   0   0   0           1       0
    1   0   0           0       1
    2   0   1           0       0
2   0   0   0           0       1
    1   0   1           0       0
```

Then you just have to groupby the index and merge them using `sum` (because we know that there will only be one or zero after get_dummies):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).groupby(level=0).agg('sum')
```

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you are using the exact code I have written? There is no error either?

Comment: I am sorry it's working now maybe I was facing any technical problem well Thank you bro

Comment: No problem :) You can accept the solution if it answered your question.